# Can any method of System.Type throw a SecurityException?

Tags: c#, .net

Normally, MSDN lists all possible exceptions per method, but at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/424c79hc(v=vs.110).aspx) page it doesn't seem to, yet the example features a try block for `SecurityException`. Does this mean that a `SecurityException` is possible? What if the type is not visible?

Comment: Yes - the documentation is not required to give an exhaustive list of all possible exceptions.

Comment: `System.Type` is not part of the reflection namespace, is it plausible for the method to throw a SecurityException?

Comment: @toplel32 neither is `SecurityException`.  There's no restriction to raising exceptions across namespaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to have a full list of exceptions for every method. Did you for example ever see an `OutOfMemoryException` noted in the documentation?

The exceptions in the documentation are the most common exceptions, and those with a specific reason bound to the use of that method. Also, noting these exceptions gives an easy way of documenting method parameters.

Some exceptions are also thrown in deeper layers, like the `Win32Exception` (which you will see in some file operations), your `SecurityException` (possibly related to [CAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) and others. Those are not specific for that method, but for the framework as a whole.

For your `SecurityException`: The [Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does give some useful hints.

Comment: To be fair, it would be nice to have documentation on what would _cause_ a `SecurityException` since it's deterministic (unlike `OutOfMemoryException`).

Comment: @DStanley: True. The [Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does give some useful hints.

Comment: I would expect CAS doing checks for dynamically generated methods, but `System.Type` is metadata.

Comment: @DStanley: you can throw that exception yourself.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I mean specifically within the `Type.GetMembers` method (assuming that's where the exception would originate in the example the OP linked to).

Comment: I don't know much about Java, even though I've been using it off and on for the last year or so for an Android app, but doesn't Java have some kind of system for trying to make the list of all possible exceptions available for all methods? Which, when I was confronted with it, I thought was a silly idea, or at least the idea of forcing you to say whether or not your method will throw an exception. In real life it just results in try-catch structures that swallow exceptions.

Comment: @RenniePet: Not sure, but that would mean that even [`substring(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) (just as an example) should say it can throw a `OutOfMemoryException`, since it allocates memory.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I am interested in knowing if `System.Type` has any intentions to throw a `SecurityException` atm or perhabs any other particular exception. The documentation gives a clue, but it may be obsolete. I recall an enumeration member named `ReflectionPermissionFlag.TypeInformation` which may be related to this deprecation that I suspect.

As I said, it wouldn't be intuitive because `System.Type` is not part of reflection.

Comment: @toplel32: Hard to tell. You might want to take a look in the [actual source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs). `SecurityException` isn't thrown there. Maybe in a referenced type or under the hood in unmanaged code.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - The DotNET source doesn't give immediate answers, I see that `BindingFlags` is used so atleast the reflection namespace is involved, but the actual methods to fetch members are `abstract` for some reason, I'm pretty certain that calls to CLR will eventually occur, and I'm not going to dig into that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: Calling any method may lead to a `OutOfMemoryException` if you run out of memory, right? This is because deep down in the call of the method, the exception may be raised.

The documentation usually only lists the exception thrown **immediately inside the method**, not in the methods called deeper down in the call stack.

So should the documentation bloated by all possible kinds of exceptions? I guess not.